# How to include mootools js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have a website with a huge part of js functions I wnat to add a login form from mootools.
I added the form and the needed files it works but the other site is stop I know it is javascript conflict this is my header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="tr" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <!--Site CSS-->
    <link href="include-css/SCOREMIX.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Latest Jquery Lib-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Mootools - the core -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/mootools12.js"></script>
    <!-- MooSlide (show/hide login form) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/mooSlide2-moo12.js"></script>
    <!--News scroller-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jscroller-0.4.js"></script>

    <!--timer for ticking at live games and to update information each minute-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery_timer.js" ></script>
    <!-- MY JS FILES-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/script.js" ></script>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/ecmascript">
    window.addEvent('domready',function(){
        var myLogin = new mooSlide2({ slideSpeed: 1500, fadeSpeed: 500,  toggler:'login', content:'loginPanel', close: false, effects:Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut , from:'top'});
        //optional: AutoStart the slider on page load:
        //MyLogin.run();
        $('close').addEvent('click', function(e){
            e = new Event(e);
            myLogin.clearit();
            e.stop();
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
```

The script is for the mootools and the needed files are commented.
I get this error when I run the site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
```

and:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (B,C){if(B&&B.$family&&B.uid){return B;}var A=$type(B);return($[A])?$[A](B,C,this.document):null;} has no method 'ajax'
```

Do anybody could help me to know if I should change the order of the JS files or is there anything I could do to stop conflict??

P.S: When I change the place of the mootools file in the header I get different messages.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$` with `jQuery`
For example, instead of using

`$("div p").hide()` use `jQuery("div p").hide();` instead

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Aslo try this

```
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   // Do something with jQuery
   j("div p").hide();
   // Do something with another library's $()  
  $("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I have a huge files of jquery and the editation will be very hard could I do the edit to the mootools instead ? and how? and where to

Comment: Thanks the $->jQuery global replace just fixed an issue on character drag in my game and meant I can now say i support Firefox! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace order your mootool js and jquery scripts and check again?

## Example

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //no conflict jquery
        jQuery.noConflict();
        //jquery stuff
        (function($) {
            $('p').css('color','#ff0000');
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="moo1.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //moo stuff
        window.addEvent('domready',function() {
            $$('p').setStyle('border','1px solid #fc0');
        });
    </script>
```

## Try using this, Your codes

```
    <!--Site CSS-->
    <link href="include-css/SCOREMIX.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--///// MOOTOOLS /////-->
    <!-- Mootools - the core -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/mootools12.js"></script>
    <!-- MooSlide (show/hide login form) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/mooSlide2-moo12.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready',function(){
            var myLogin = new mooSlide2({ slideSpeed: 1500, fadeSpeed: 500,  toggler:'login', content:'loginPanel', close: false, effects:Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut , from:'top'});
            //optional: AutoStart the slider on page load:
            //MyLogin.run();
            $('close').addEvent('click', function(e){
                e = new Event(e);
                myLogin.clearit();
                e.stop();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!--///// JQUERY /////--> 
    <!-- Latest Jquery Lib-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>   
    <!--News scroller-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jscroller-0.4.js"></script>
    <!--timer for ticking at live games and to update information each minute-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery_timer.js" ></script>
    <!-- MY JS FILES-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/script.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // jquery scripts                              
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: but the javascript functions that I have is in separate and has a lot of function (functions.js) and other file (script.js) which has scripts when after document.ready. how to include them in my header and how to isolate them using the anonymous function

Comment: check my update answer again. btw, do you need this line? ...<script language="javascript" type="text/ecmascript">... I changed it to ...<script type="text/javascript">... test again.